# Possible to write custom content provider for existing system database?

Tags: android, provider

Not sure of the absolute utility of this but seems as though it should be possible and useful.

Can you extend `ContentProvider` to provide `URIs` representing new queries (i.e., joins across multiple tables not specified by existing `URIs`) for an existing system database?

The alternative seems to be that I need to write a series of `cursor queries` then join them -- seems like a lot of unnecessary code duplication.

I have been trying this for the contacts `database` as an exercise, but no love so far.

The crux seems to be that I cannot open a `database` in another package during the setup phase.

Am I just completely out in left field here?

It's possible as I am new to both `Java and Android`.

Comments and/or pointers to relevant resources are appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you extend ContentProvider to
>   provide URIs representing new queries
>   (i.e., joins across multiple tables
>   not specified by existing URIs) for an
>   existing system database?

Not really, only because you don't have direct access to existing system databases, in terms of SQLite. Now, creating a `ContentProvider` that performs your joins for you, as a reusability measure, is certainly doable, though I would get worried about the performance overhead of multiple cross-process hops.

Comment: Hi Mark -- sorry for my egregious lapse in marking as answered :)